# Missing required icon file deliveing iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin, icons, application-loader, xamarin.forms

In a **Xamarin.Forms** project...

I am trying to upload my IPA file to App Store (using Application Loader) but I am getting the following errors:

[image]

...but in my **Resources** folder **I have** the related files:

Icon-60@2x.png -> 120x120

Icon-76@2x.png -> 152x152

Icon-76.png -> 76x76

So...I don't understand where is the problem, because the files are still there, and all configured as **BundleResource**.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fix it adding this in Info.plist file

```
  <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
  <array>
    <string>Icon-60@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-76.png</string>
    <string>Icon-76@2x.png</string>    
  </array>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a [Asset Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog.html) feature of XCode

But for support iOS 6, your solutions is [right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114843/icons-asset-catalog-and-info-plist-confusion)